# Concatenate Double Quote for a large number without E+

Tags: excel-2010

I have some really big numbers with me in an excel. I need to concatenate double quote in both the end of each number.

Like I have number:

```
20150909110448800000000000 in A1
20150909105944800000000000 in B1
and 20150909110448700000000000 in C1
```

And i need the output like :

```
"20150909110448800000000000","20150909105944800000000000","20150909110448700000000000" in D1
```

I have tried changing the format of cell D1 by selecting Format Cell --> Number --> Custom --> 0 --> "OK"

Then Put the concatenate function in D1.

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),A1,CHAR(34),",",CHAR(34),B1,CHAR(34),",",CHAR(34),C1,CHAR(34))
```

But it is giving output as :

```
"2.01509091104488E+25","2.01509091059448E+25","2.01509091104487E+25"
```

Instead of what I expect.

Can you please provide the solution to get rid of this E+ in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your numbers to text and then concat. As you output will be text if you add `" "`.

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(34),TEXT(A1,0),CHAR(34),TEXT(B1,0),CHAR(34))
```